# Apache Solr- Parent Child Indexing

Tags: apache, solr

I am new to Apache Solr and need little help in understanding the parent-child or Nested documents indexing because I can't find anything on google regarding what I am looking for. So here it is what I need to ask

If I index a document with doc-id `comment1` and then I index a nested document with parent doc-id `post1` and child document with doc-id `comment1`. Will solr index  `comment1` twice? Once individually and once with its parent?

Secondly,
Will it have any effect on the relevancy score calculation of the document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

referring back to [Yonik's Blog](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/), you'll have to form a single document object which will be posted to SOLR in one go.

> **Lucene Index Representation:** Lucene has a flat object model and does not really support “nesting” of documents in the index. Lucene
>   *does* support adding a list of documents atomically and contiguously (i.e. a virtual “block”), and this is the feature used by Solr to
>   implement “nested objects”.
>
> When you add a parent document with 3 children, these appear in the
>   index contiguously as
>
> child1, child2, child3, parent There is no Lucene-level information
>   that links parent and child, or distinguishes this parent/child block
>   from the other documents in the index that come before or after.
>   Successfully using parent/child relationships relies on more
>   information being provided at query time.
>
> **Limitations:** All children of a parent document must be indexed
>   together with the parent document. One cannot update any document
>   (parent or child) individually. The entire block needs to be
>   re-indexed of any changes need to be made.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @segFaulter . I have gone through the blog but still I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for. Can you please explain it in simple terms? What is actually happening? Suppose I have indexed a document `comment1` then I index it again as a child element with another document say `post1` will it be indexed twice or not?